# Can I setup nameservers to point to other nameservers?

Tags: dns, nameservers

We are whitelabeling some website software, but in order to use it, our clients must point their domains to the software's nameservers. We'll say ns1.softwareco.com and ns2.softwareco.com.

Since we're whitelabeling, I don't want our clients to see Software Co's name in the name servers.

I could easily mirror Software Co's DNS settings, but if Software Co updates them in the future, my settings would be incorrect.

Is it possible to just point my nameservers ns1.whitelabelco.com and ns2.whitelabelco.com to Software Co's nameservers?

Comment: Try to set an CNAME and point from it to your servername.

Comment: Is this bind? There is an upstream parameter you can specify in named.conf if so.

Answer (score 0):

Your best way of achieving this is to follow the lead of other companies.

For example, if you look at how [github](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) allows the configuring of custom domain names for their pages product. Which is whitelabelling in effect.

The two options you have are basically, that you have a static IP address that will last for the lifetime of your service. Which would mean you would need to buy that address, complete with a contract to ensure it didn't need to be changed. You could place that address infront of load balancers etc, so it could be directed to multiple servers at the backend (even multiple locations)

The simpler option is to offer a CNAME redirection to your clients.

You tell your clients that you have service.example.com and they should point their servers to that with a CNAME record. so their clients will see www.domain.com but that will be redirected to your site.

The downside of a CNAME record over an IP Address, is that the end user can see that it is a whitelabel product. The problem is that DNS is an open system, and no matter what you do with it the end user will be able to see what you've done and find out that you are hosting that site.

The **only** way around that is to use an IP Address.